# Android : Avoid app to quit after automation testing

Tags: java, android, automation, robotium

I am writing android automation test using Robotium and after successful test, I want to take screenshot of the app.

The problem is however that the application quits after the test is completed and my job for screen capture takes  home screenshot which is not desired.

Is there a way I could stop my application to quit so that the app screen is active and I get the desired screenshot?

Below is test case which I have written. Also, I am not using any `tearDown` activity.

```
public class MyTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

private static final String LAUNCH_ACTIVITY_NAME = "com.demo.activity.MyActivity";

private Solo solo;

private static Class<?> splashActivityClass;
static {
    try {
        splashActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCH_ACTIVITY_NAME);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public Test() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    super(splashActivityClass);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

@SuppressLint({ "SimpleDateFormat", "NewApi" })
public void testAllCountries() {

     // test goes here...
}
```

I am taking screenshot via `adb` command which I execute in a separate job using `Java Runtime`.

Comment: did you try to `sleep` thread in `tearDown()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue a little while ago, when the screenshots I was keeping were not in sync with the tests I was executing.
I managed to do so by adding a simple

```
solo.sleep(1000);
```

After taking the screenshot.

Hope this can help you too

Answer (score 0):

You can use sleep to hold for some sec at end using:

```
solo.sleep(2000);
```